# Easy way to calculate word-count in Latex for Mac?

Tags: pdf, texshop, msword, word-count

I am using TexShop and was wondering if there is an easy way to find the wordcount in a document ?
The way I do it now is copy and paste the PDF document into Word to calculate the word count. Is there a way I can do this directly from the PDF file in MACOS's Preview ? Or through LaTeX directly ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try `detex document.tex | wc -w`

(`detex` does a decent, but  not perfect, job at eliminating LaTeX commands, if you use such to write part of the text, the count will be off. And I don't remember offhand how it handles accents, i.e. `l'H\^opital` might give too many words).

Comment: Where do I place this command ?

Comment: Run it from the command line. `detex` is part of TeXlive, at least.

Comment: I don't mean to be bothersome, but can you please provide more info ? Where is the command line ? How do I run it ?

Comment: I don't know Mac that well, but it is a Unixy system. There should be some way to get a terminal where you can enter commands, in that you can `cd` to where your document lives. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Oh okay I got you. Mac uses `Terminal`. So I `cd` into the folder and run this ? Will try it now.

Answer (score 10):

[TexCount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/) will do a word count for you and also break it down per section etc.
Available both as a web-app as well as a download, and comes packaged with TeX Live. Can be invoked in the command line with `texcount mytexfile.tex`.

Comment: I've seen that thank you, but I was afraid my code will be stored somewhere and might be marked as plagiarism when I submit my report.

Comment: @NLed -- `texcount` comes with TeX Live, and can be invoked from the commandline (assuming Bash, or equivalent) as follows: `texcount mytexfile.tex`.  It is much better than `detex` + `wc`.

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned that there is also a downloadable version.